# Angular route resolve returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**app.js**

```
angular
        .module('yelp',['ngRoute'])
            .config(config);

    config.$inject=['$routeProvider','YelpServiceProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
            })
            .when('/restaurants',{
                templateUrl:'partials/restaurants.html',
                controller:'RestaurantsController',
                controllerAs:'rstrntsCtrl',
                resolve:{
                    restaurants:getRestaurants
                }
            });
    }

    function getRestaurants(YelpService,$route){        
        YelpService.getRestaurants($route.current.params,function(response){
            console.log(response.data.businesses); **//Data printed here**
            return response.data.businesses;
        });
    }
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular
        .module('yelp')
            .controller('RestaurantsController',RestaurantsController);

    RestaurantsController.$inject=['restaurants'];
    function RestaurantsController(restaurants){
        var rstrntsCtrl=this;
        console.log(restaurants);  **// got undefined here**
    }
```

Resolve function makes an $http call to fetch the data. It is then passed to the controller. I am able to print data in resolve function but cannot pass that to controller (received undefined). can someone point out where i went wrong

Comment: You  have to return `YelpService` along with the response but in your code you are returning only response

Comment: What do you mean by return YelpService. i did not get that.

Comment: If i return yelpService, what is the use of writing resolve in config instead i can directly inject YelpService in that controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss injection here:

```
 RestaurantsController.$inject=['restaurants','YelpServiceProvider'];
function RestaurantsController(restaurants,YelpServiceProvider)
```

you need to inject YelpServiceProvider in the consumer(controller) not in the config (though you didn't quite inject it to the config either...)